# How do I disable rapid charging?

Tags: charging, google-pixel

When I plug my phone in the AC charger, it says "charging rapidly" and charges from 20% to 100 for less than 90mins. Is it possible to charge it normally? When I charge it over USB it takes up to 7 hours to fully charge which is too slow. Phone is Pixel XL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Pixel XL allows for slower charging, if a non USB-C adapter is used.

From the support area at Google on the section concerning charging. See the suggestion #2 for your concern:

> *Which power adapters and cables to use*
>
> 1. Pixel phones use USB-C with USB 2.0 power adapters and cables.
> 2. To charge your Pixel phone with a USB-A power adapter, use a USB-C to USB-A cable. **This will charge your Pixel phone more slowly than USB-C**.
> 3. Other Android cables and power adapters might not work with Pixel phones.
> 4. Pixel phones can't charge wirelessly.